# How to position a textView above recyclerView?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a problem related with my xml code. Here is a screenshot from my page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6kvA.jpg
In this photo you can see that the `Text View` which says "Popular Tv Series" is over the recycler view items. I want to position this textView above the `recycler view` so they dont't cover each other. Here is the xml code for both layout that i am using. I tried playing with the constraints but it just seems that the `textView` is fixed. Thanks!

fragment_search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ui.SearchFragment.SearchFragment">


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_search_bottomnav"
        android:hint="@string/searchbar_hint"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/dark_red"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_text_layout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/search_fragment_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_view_recommended"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_recommended"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/searchFragment_mostPopular"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

item_fragmentsearch_popular.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movie_image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: do you want textview scrollable over recycler view?

Comment: No no u just want to position the textView above the recycler view and as i scroll down everything above the recyclerview will be removed. But i know how to do that with coordinator layout i just don't know how to position the textview above the recyclerview not like now inside the recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Declare textview before recyclerview .
Assign height=0dp to  recyclerview, contraints will automatically assign height to it.

Other Note: if you assign match parent width to any view then you dont need to write start to start and end to end contraint.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You really helped me.